# Completely revert a folder in TortoiseSVN

Tags: svn, tortoisesvn

I have been playing around with code in a folder and I now want to complete revert back to the previous revision.  I have never once committed anything and I simply want to completely get rid of everything that I've ever done as if I never made any changes at all.

This should be simple enough.  I'm following the steps detailed [here](http://tortoisesvn.net/docs/release/TortoiseSVN_en/tsvn-howto-rollback.html) but I'm getting tripped up on the last step:

> You have reverted the changes within your working copy. Check the
>   results, then commit the changes.

I have reverted the folder to a previous revision but the folder still shows all of the files that I made changes to.  I don't want tot commit these files.  I simply want them gone and the reverted versions in their place.

What am I missing? Should I go ahead and commit my files?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you want to undo all changes you made in a file since the last update you need to select the file, right click to pop up the context menu and then select the command TortoiseSVN → Revert A dialog will pop up showing you the files that you've changed and can revert. Select those you want to revert and click on OK 
check [this](http://tortoisesvn.net/docs/release/TortoiseSVN_en/tsvn-dug-revert.html)

Comment: This will revert the previously existing files but any new files I added will still be there.  I need to get rid of the new files, as well.

Comment: you will need to delete them as you delete any other file on disk

Comment: Fair enough.  I was hoping that there was an easy way to start from scratch and avoid having to hunt for each new file.

Comment: use the "delete unversioned items" button the revert screen

Answer (score 2):

If you're trying to get rid of new files that you don't want committed, you might want to look at the TortoiseSVN -> Cleanup command, [here](http://tortoisesvn.net/docs/release/TortoiseSVN_en/tsvn-dug-cleanup.html). There's an option to delete unversioned files, and to delete ignored files.

Edit: this was meant as an elaboration on Surender's answer.

Comment: Ah, excellent.  That's exactly what I needed.  If I had 15 rep, I'd upvote you.